# Objective-C: CGRectContainsPoint Trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have this method, which calling when my button was dragged with UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
- (void)wasDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[recognizer view];
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:button];

    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + translation.x, button.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:button];

    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)  {

        for (UIView *field in self.fieldsArray) {

            CGPoint fieldCenter = [field convertPoint:field.center toView:self.view];

            if (CGRectContainsPoint (button.frame, fieldCenter)) {
                NSLog(@"done");
                break;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"nope");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My `self.fieldsArray` creates in other method:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        UIView *field = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * (widthOfField + 3), 0, widthOfField, 50 )];

        [field setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:70/255 green:70/255 blue:70/255 alpha:1.0]];
        [field.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
        [field.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [field.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
        [field.layer setCornerRadius:10];

        [self.fieldsArray addObject:field];

        [self.fieldsView addSubview:field];
    }
```

The question is: why when I drag my button to fields number 1 or 3 or 5 etc I have "done" message. And when I drag button to fields 2 or 4 or 6 etc, I have "nope"?

If I delete `break;`:
For example, when I drag the button on the field number 5 (and all of my 6), I have log: `nope, nope, done, nope, nope, nope`
on the field number 3: `nope, done, nope, nope, nope, nope`

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are doing but setting `button.center` won't update the `frame` immediately. Instead of using `button.frame`, I would calculate the new frame manually for the test from. Also, make sure that `self.view` is the superview of button, otherwise the point conversion won't work correctly.

Comment: self.view is superview for button. What do you mean that button.center won't update frame immediately?

Comment: Changing `frame`, `center` or `bounds` of a view starts an animation (they are all animatable properties). That means that accessing them immediately after assigning does not have return the expected value.